# Handle Activity Finishing Event In Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there anything similar to `FormClosingEvent` in Xamarin.android?

I have two activities - `A` and `B`. `B` is saving some data and is called from `A` on button click. I have list of data in `A` and want to automatically update it after `B` activity is finished.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `StartActivityForResult` with Activity A starting activity B in the following manner

```
var myIntent = new Intent (this, typeof(ActivityB));
StartActivityForResult (myIntent, 0);
```

ActivityA should also then override `OnActivityResult` waiting to respond to activity B's response code and update as necessary.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
     // Do whatever needs to be done in A 
  }
}
```

This is all documented quite well in [Xamarin's Android documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_activity_for_result/)

Comment: OK, now follow-up question:
What if I have `A`, `B` and `C` activities. `A` is calling `B`, `B` is calling `C` and I want to do same for `C` and `A` activities. Should I send `OK` result from `C` to `B` and then from `B` to `A` or can I do it straight from `C` to `A`?

Comment: Never mind. I found very simple solution. I can do what I wanted in `OnResume()` method. 

`StartActivityForResult` is for sending data back to first activity. And I don't have anything to send back. I just have to call a method after second activity is closed, so `OnResume` is what I need.

Thanks anyway