# Starting an Intent.ActionView without stopping the current Activity

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

I am coding a Xamarin Android application, and have a question in regards to starting an `Activity`.

How can I start an `Activity`, without stopping the current `Activity`?

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(androidMapLocationVideoViewModel.videoAsset.webAddress));
StartActivity(intent);
```

I am using this code to start the default application to load a video at a url.

Currently, the associated application starts up the video, however, my application then quits out.

I have added the following to the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I wish to be able to start the default application to view the video at a desired url, but let the user come back to my own application by pressing the back button.

How should I code this? I have done some research, but cannot find an answer to this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Default application means media player or your custom player....you are playing video with third party player

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this answer [Handle Activity Finishing Event In Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096579/handle-activity-finishing-event-in-xamarin-android/26097501#26097501) .

You want to use StartActivityForResult with your activity starting the video in the following manner

```
Intent intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(androidMapLocationVideoViewModel.videoAsset.webAddress));
StartActivityForResult (myIntent, 0);
```

Where the int 0 in the above code is an integer parameter identifying the call (which you can then use in the OnActivityResult call back.  Your activity should also then override OnActivityResult waiting to respond to the player's response as necessary.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == myIntCode) {
     // Do whatever needs to be done if anything
  }
}
```

This is all documented quite well in [Xamarin's Android documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_activity_for_result/)